# Android Bitmap bigger than heapSize

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm getting the error: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=12295KB, Allocated=3007KB, Bitmap Size=15621KB)`

The bitmap size is larger than my heapSize.. So how can I make the bitmap smaller? Here is the code where it crashes:

```
private Bitmap getPicture(int position) {
    Bitmap bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFileLocations.get(position));
    Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(), bmpOriginal.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bmResult);
    tempCanvas.rotate(90, bmpOriginal.getWidth()/2, bmpOriginal.getHeight()/2);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, null);
    bmpOriginal.recycle();
}
```

it crashes at line:

```
 Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(), bmpOriginal.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

and my decodeFile:

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(String f){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale*=2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Failed to decode file");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where you use your `decodeFile` method. You're just using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`.

Comment: Oh wow, I was using it elsewhere but I guess I must have changed it when i was trying things. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale down your image to be in VM Budget...

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile( filename, options );
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = 4; 

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( filename, options );
        if ( bitmap != null ) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bitmap, width, height, false );
        }
```

Change sample size to whatever you want like 2, 4, 6, 8 etc..

For full details refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) from Android developers site which was posted rescently, it clearly states what you need to do to be in VM budget..

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

It appears that you are using the `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` method instead of the method you have posted.

Also it looks like the only information you are keeping from `bmpOriginal` are its dimensions. So why not just use `BitmapFactory.inJustDecodeBounds` like you do in your `decodeFile` method.  Or do just recycle the bitmap before you create the new one while retaining its dimensions, like this:

```
int width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();
int height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
bmpOriginal.recycle();
Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was recently covered in AndroidDevelopers+ :

https://plus.google.com/103125970510649691204/posts/1oSFSyv3pRj

Comment: and about a million times on SO